# Merge multiple list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries and I want to get the list of 2 of the keys in the list. Here is how I do it now:

```
l_id = [d['id1'] for d in l_data]
l_id.extend([d['id2'] for d in l_data])
```

Is there a pythonic way to do the list comprehension once and get the same result? (id order does not matter)

Comment: Show us the list please.

Comment: l_data = [ {'id1':1, 'col1':'va1', 'id2':1001}, {'id1':2, 'col1':'va2', 'id2':1002}, ....]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
l_id = [d[key] for key in ['id1', 'id2'] for d in l_data]
```

Comment: I think s/he wants them in the opposite order.

Comment: maybe add `if key in d` to make sure there won't be  a KeyError

Comment: alexis: my answer is consistent with OP's example. If op indicates that key is optionally present in d I would modify as Julien suggests.

Comment: alexis: oh I see, all from id1 first. I've modified.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over your dictionaries items in each iteration and check if the key is `id1` or `id2` then preserve the value :

```
[j for d in l_data for i,j in d.items() if i=='id1' or i=='id2']
```

As an alternative way you can also use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with `map` function:

```
>>> data = [ {'id1':1, 'col1':'va1', 'id2':1001}, {'id1':2, 'col1':'va2', 'id2':1002}]
>>> map(itemgetter('id1','id2'),data)
[(1, 1001), (2, 1002)]
```

Comment: This gives something completely different than the OP's code does.

Comment: @alexis Its just the result of second part using `itemgetter` and as i said its an alternative answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
l_id = [d[key] for key in ('id1', 'id2') for d in l_data]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all values of key `id1`, followed by all values of key `id2`, you can do it like this:

```
l_id = [ d[k] for k in ["id1", "id2"] for d in l_data if k in d ]
```

If you already know that every dictionary has all the IDs you need, you can skip the test (`if k in d`).